# WP8 using can't install WPtoolkit

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, nuget, windows-phone-toolkit

I'm crazy with WPtoolkit.  I'm using nuget to install the WPtoolkitbecause I want to use contextmenu in my project.  But every time I install in to my project, it popped up this a dialogue show me "WPtoolkit 4.2013.08.16 already installed!"

[image]

BUT I CAN'T FIND IT IN MY PROJECT!!

Anyone know what's wrong with my project or my VS2012?

Answer (score 0):

1. Open `packages.config` and remove the following line:
2. Just in case, open Package Manager Console and run:

   Uninstall-Package WPtoolkit
3. Try running the following command again:

   Install-Package WPtoolkit